# Looping through an array to render multiple charts

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, arraylist, charts

I am creating a webapp in react that shows data based on Economic, social, and political indicators. Since the data is too big to render on to one single chart (a nightmare for mobile UI) I've decided to split the data into 4 objects in an array. I am trying to find a way to loop through that array. Here is the code

```
import React from 'react';
import { Bar } from 'react-chartjs-2';
import ChartDataSource from 'chartjs-plugin-datasource';

const config = {
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
                borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
                borderWidth: 1,
                hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
                hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            },
        ],
    },

    options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        plugins: {
            datasource: {
                type: 'sheet',
                url: 'GDP1.xlsx', {/*<----- This is where the array gets looped*/}
                rowMapping: 'index',
            },
        },
        title: {
            display: true,
            text: 'GDP per country',
        },
        scales: {
            xAxes: [
                {
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Countries',
                    },
                },
            ],
            yAxes: [
                {
                    id: '2018',
                    gridLines: {
                        drawOnChartArea: false,
                    },
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'GDP',
                    },
                },
            ],
        },
    },
};

function BarChart() {
    const graphslist = [ {/* Ths is the array i want to loop through*/}
        { url: 'GDP1.xlsx' },
        { url: 'GDP2.xlsx' },
        { url: 'GDP3.xlsx' },
        { url: 'GDP4.xlsx' },
    ];
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>GDP per country</h2>
            <Bar
                data={config.data}
                options={config.options}
                width={100}
                height={100}
                plugins={[ChartDataSource]}
            />
        </div>
    );
}

export default BarChart;
```

I've been trying to use the .map function so config.options.plugins.url loops over the 4 objects in the array therefore rendering 4 charts but I keep getting unexpected token. Any help is welcome

Answer (score 0):

you can try this without the plugins.

```
const theDatasets= (()=>{
let arr = []
      for (let i = 0; i < graphslist .length; i++) {

          arr.push(
            {
              data: graphslist [i],
              backgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.2)',
            borderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
            borderWidth: 1,
            hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,0.4)',
            hoverBorderColor: 'rgba(255,99,132,1)',
              label: graphslist [i],
                   
            }
          )
        }
      
      return arr
})()
```

on the render

```
<Bar
                data={theDatasets}
                options={config.options} // your option without plugins
                width={100}
                height={100}
                
            />
```